# Python Panda Dataframe Count Specific Values from List

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a list:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c']
```

and a Pandas dataframe (df) that has a column named "rating". How can I get the count for number of occurrence of a rating **while iterating my list?** For example, here is what I need:

```
for item in myList
   # Do a bunch of stuff in here that takes a long time
   # want to do print statement below to show progress
   # print df['rating'].value_counts().a <- I can do this, 
   #     but want to use variable 'item'
   # print df['rating'].value_counts().item <- Or something like this
```

I know I can get counts for all distinct values of 'rating', but that is not what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do it this way, you can use `.loc` to filter the df prior to getting the size of the resulting df.

```
mylist = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'rating':['a','a','b','c','c','c','d','e','f']})


for item in mylist:
    print(item, df.loc[df['rating']==item].size)
```

Output

```
a 2
b 1
c 3
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. There is a lot going on behind the hood that I did not include, and my print statement is sort of a progress capture, since each iteration can take a long time. Because of that I did not want to just get everything after my dataframe is complete (I am adding records to it each pass).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking about this problem as one of going "from the list to the Dataframe" it might be easiest to flip it around:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'rating':['a','a','b','c','c','c','d','e','f']})

ValueCounts = df['rating'].value_counts()
ValueCounts[ValueCounts.index.isin(mylist)]
```

Output:

```
c    3
a    2
b    1
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a for loop, just do:

```
df['rating'].value_counts()[mylist]
```

Or to make it a dictionary:

```
df['rating'].value_counts()[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_dict()
```